# tcp/ip without ip in .net

Tags: .net, tcp, ip, sctp

Strange title I know, but please hear me out. I am looking for a version of TcpClient and TcpListener which don't use IP. In essence, I would like to be able to use all the TCP benefits (reliable & ordered) on top of any protocol of my choosing (UDP, ICMP, DNS, carrier pigeon).

Is there a way I could somehow tap into what TCP is passing down to the IP layer?

Thanks,
Fidel

Edit:

I want a reliable protocol (eg. TCP) which can pump data into a stream, and read data from a stream, without knowing exactly how the stream transports that data.

I have explicit control over that stream. I just need TCP to send information to that stream instead of its regular underlying layer.

Comment: Do you have at least SLIGHT idea, how does networking works?

Comment: TCP on top of UDP? They both work at the transport layer... And DNS is application layer... see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model

Comment: What's the **concrete** problem that led you to search for a solution like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[There was an experiment run to get TCP working with Pigeons.](http://www.blug.linux.no/rfc1149/)
[Recently there also was an experiment using Humans and Xylophones.](http://www.networkworld.com/news/2012/051112-researcher-runs-ip-network-over-259231.html)

Comment: I think that was ICMP/IP with pigeons. Did they actually use TCP with that?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this and you do not need to use TCP/IP.

Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bsb3c8f.aspx), you can pass different address types not just TCP/IP.

But remember if you are talking about UDP, ICMP, ... they are different protocols not different addressing schemes.